# How do I exit one-handed mode for the lock pattern screen?

Tags: lock-screens, pattern-lock

My lock screen is in one-handed mode, but the rest of my phone is in normal mode. My settings have got one-handed mode turned off. How do I turn it off for the pattern screen?!

[image]
[image]

Comment: Please check if lock screen settings have something related to this

Comment: Hmm, bizarrely, soon after posting this question, the lock screen reverted to its normal size. I didn't change anything, and am at a total loss to explain this behaviour

Comment: Strange are the ways of Android :-)